# Puppeteer cant intercept xhr response json

Tags: javascript, node.js, xmlhttprequest, puppeteer

when I visit this URL:
https://www.petedge.com/tp-cat-grooming-bag#sku_id=TP463%2017
In the chrome networks tab I can see this network GET request to a url that returns JSON data:
[image]

I have a node.js puppeteer program where I am trying to intercept this network request but it is not working.

```
    await page.setRequestInterception(true)

    //intercept requests
    page.on('request', (request) => {
      request.continue()
    })

    //intercept responses
    page.on('response', async (response) => {
        console.log("response.url() = ", response.url())
        //widget.trustpilot.com/trustbox-data
        /*
        if(response.url().includes("widget.trustpilot.com/trustbox-data/")){
            console.log("   GOOD response.url() = ", response.url())
            const res = await page.waitForResponse(response);
            console.log("res=",res);
        }
        */
    })
  
    await page.goto(producturl, {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
    });

    console.log('loaded')
```

In my console.log output I can see it intercepts the xhr requests if i ctrl+f there is no request with the text "trustbox-data" in the URL, why can I see this request on the page when I visit it but it doesnt get intercepted by puppeteer?